# Search query speed

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm creating a database in SQLite as follows:

```cpp
QSqlQuery create_address;
create_address.prepare("CREATE TABLE addresses (addressid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, address TEXT UNIQUE)");
QSqlQuery create_devices;
create_devices.prepare("CREATE TABLE devices (ch TEXT PRIMARY KEY, addressid INTEGER REFERENCES addresses(addressid))");

create_devices.exec();
create_address.exec();
```

I need to access this database a lot of times (~660'000) passing `ch` and retrieving the corresponding address, the `ch` passed, could not be in the database (empty string is returned).

To do so, I made the following query:

```cpp
//outside loop
QSqlQuery find_address;
find_address.prepare("SELECT address FROM addresses,devices WHERE devices.addressid = addresses.addressid AND devices.ch = :chcode");

//in loop
find_address.bindValue(":chcode",QString::fromStdString(ch_code));

find_address.exec();
```

The problem is that this process is very slow (it takes almost 12 minutes to finish all the 660'000 searches).

Before this, I tried with an `INNER JOIN`, but the performance was pretty much the same.

Is there a better way to write the query and/or structure the DB to get a faster execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a loop with SQL query, you can wrap it into transaction which may improve the performance:

```
QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
.........
// your loop
.........
QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
```

Also the performance may be improved by adding indexes. In your case index can be created on the fields `devices.addressid` and `devices.ch`. In sqlite console do the following:

```
CREATE INDEX devices_index ON devices(ch, addressid);
```

Comment: A transaction has a large effect only for statements that write. `(ch)` or `(ch,addressid)` would be much better.

Comment: I found the problem, when creating the ```create_devices``` query i wrote ```PRMARY KEY``` instead of ```PRIMARY KEY```, fixing the typo brought the execution time down to ~1 minute. Your solution brought it down to ~50 seconds which is acceptable for my application so your solution was the most helpful one

Answer (score -1):

Without any measurement or insights how the tables `addresses` and `devices` look like, it's hard to give precise advice.

Maybe the join is the bottleneck, so you can try to create a view first. This would avoid joining two tables, 659000 times. [See here on how to create a view.](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)

Next (shot in the dark), instead of executing 660000 queries, make batches. For example, replace `AND devices.ch = :chcode` by `AND devices.ch IN(:chcodelist)` and glue multiple chcodes together. Depending on the content, take care of their escaping yourself.